# No DLL generated for iOS project in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am trying to create a Xamarin Forms project that is full of custom renderers. The intention is to use the DLLs created in other projects too.

When I build the project, I get projectname.dll & projectName.Droid.dll in android but I only get projectName.dll in iOS 
There is no projectName.iOS.dll

The build mode is debug, on simulator. 
What's missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should create an iOS library project manually, add the xamarin Forms Nuget and your custom renderers to it.

By default creating a xamarin forms project only creates a pcl, and 2 application projects (iOS and android).

Comment: Is that a guess or something you have tried before? Sounds tempting though. Will try

Comment: I've created the xamsvg component which contains a forms iOS library and is working nicely since a year

Comment: Do I need to do the same for Android too?

Comment: Well this is the way to go, yes. If it currently works, it's only luck and may break at a later update.

Comment: Yes that makes sense. Just to ask how you do it, if I create a iOS library project with all renderers in. Then how do you test the controls? Do you use the reference of the Library project in your iOS Application project that was created by Xamarin Forms? 
How do you architect it? 
Thanks for your help. Appreciate it.

Comment: Yes like any library. In this iOS lib add a ref to a pcl project where you defined the controls (not the pcl project of a forms app). Do the same for amdroid. Then to use the controls add 1) to the app's pcl project a ref to the control's pcl project. 2) to the app's iOS project a ref from both the pcl control project and the associated iOS library project.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108468/discussion-between-supreet-and-softlion).

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work. I created a new solution that has 2 class library projects (cl for XF & cl for iOS). So my new solution now only have these 2 projects. 

in iOS I am referencing the pcl project, in the pcl I created a simple extended entry control & a renderer for it in the iOS class library project. 

Both projects have latest XF nugets. 

If then I try to use the DLLs created in a new Xamarin Forms project  I get the following exception. 

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'TXControls' or one of its dependencies
File name:

Answer (score 1):

To solve that FileIOException (dll not found issue updated in comments above) All I had to do was to create some blank Init methods in custom renderers & call them in my sample app's AppDelegate & MainActivity just after Forms.Init & before ApplicationLoad. 
That did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps someone else out there might need a solution to this as well, I also needed to implement this into a project, and it turned out that no .dll file is being generated for iOS project rather a .exe file is generated which can be imported as .NET Assembly into another Xamarin iOS project's reference just like you'd do for a dll file.

I hope this helps